# How to examine the godness-of-fit of a Conjoint model (predict values in a holdout sample)?

Tags: r

I am trying to apply an existing Conjoint model to a new data set (holdout sample) in order to determine the goodness of the fit.

I run a Conjoint analysis and obtain a model. The conjoint function automatically generates a graphical output, Residual standard error, Multiple R-squared,F-statistic, adjusted R-squared, p-value, and Part worths (utilities).

Now I want to run the Conjoint model on the holdout samples to know how the model performs on the new data.
Ideally, I would like to find out what the best practice of obtaining the goodness of fit of a an existing model based on new data looks like.

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]! At the current state your question is off topic for SO.

Comment: This is more likely a question for "cross validated". One simple principle is that actual and predicted should be close to reflect your model's ability of prediction.